# Debugging API and unit test from same solution

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WebAPI project and a test project for API in same solution as shown below.

[image]

The code of controller is shown below. As you notice I have a breakpoint setup on the Get method

[image]

The API is working fine such as via postman or browser as shown below.

[image]

One of the unit test is just calling the same Get API via HttpClient class.

[image]

Problem is I want to setup both projects (API and test) so that I can debug code from a single  solution. For that I have setup both of these projects as start up

[image]

If I hit F5 key to start debugging, I get following warning which makes sense

[image]

In order to debug the unit test and choose “Debug Tests” option as shown below

[image]

With that I get following exception that A connection with the server could not be established.

[image]

In summary
1.  The API is working fine as I can test it via PostMan
2.  If I move the unit test project in a separate solution, then I can debug API fine. The breakpoint get hit and everything is fine

My question is how to debug this when I have both projects in the same solution?

Comment: You could try using an in-memory test server.

Comment: Can you give any example of how to do that?

Comment: I don't see this link talks about in-memory test server or how to solve the issue that I have.

Comment: Check this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing#integration-testing

Comment: Along with this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing#integration-testing-aspnet-core

Comment: I included the TestServer mechanism described in the links that @nkosi provided but still not able to hit breakpoint on my API methods

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Nops. I just created a different solution that connect to the API solution. Let me know in case you find any better way